# Is it possible to load a user command from an in-memory namespace?

Tags: dyalog

From what I can tell, user commands can only be loaded from namespace scripts located in the directories specified by the SALT `cmddir` setting.

But I have an interest in loading a user command directly from an in-memory namespace, without ever having a namespace script reside on a locally accessible disk.

An example use case might be loading a namespace that defines one or more user commands from a remote repository via `]get`, and then "installing" the user commands into the workspace directly from memory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news: No, you cannot currently do that.

Good news: I'm working on a rewrite of the user command system which makes this trivial to do.

Source: I'm in charge of the user command system at Dyalog.